# $f(x)=2x+6-f(1)$, $f(8) = ?$

Tags: functions

> $$f(x)=2x+6-f(1)$$
>
> $$f(8) = ?$$

I'm trying to evaluate the function shown above.

$$f(x)-f(1)=2x+6$$

Substituting $x = 1$,  then we have that

$$f(x)-2(1)+6=2x+6 \implies f(x)+4=2x+6 \implies f(x) = 2x+10$$

Now solving it for $f(8)$

$$f(8) = 2(8)+10 =26$$

I think I've gone wrong somewhere. Could you show it up?

Regards

Comment: After you substitute $1$ for $x$, why $x$ still appears in the following reasoning?

Comment: @xbh Shouldn't $x$ still appear there?

Comment: Your idea, to let $x=1$, is good...but you don't seem to follow through.

Comment: Substituting $x=1$, $f(1)=4$. You can solve it now.

Comment: $f(x)-f(1)=2x+6$ is wrong.  True is $f(x)+f(1)=2x+6$

Comment: You recieved 6 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Two mistakes are immediatelly apparent:

One: The expressions $$f(x)=2x+6-f(1)$$

and $$f(x)-f(1)=2x+6$$

are **not** equivalent.

Two, after you substitute $x=1$, the expression still contains $x$. This makes little sense. If you *substitute* $x$ for $1$, then you have to replace **every** $x$ with $1$.

Therefore, taking the expression $f(x)=2x+6-f(1)$, and plugging in, say, $x=3$, would yield

$$f(3)=2\cdot 3 + 6-f(1)$$

Not that no $x$ appears anywhere in the expression.

---

On the plus side, your idea of plugging in $x=1$ is the right way to go. Try again, and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$f(x)=2x+6-f(1) \implies f(1)=2+6-f(1) \implies f(1)=4$$

and

$$f(x)=2x+6-4=2x+2$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)+ f(1) = 2x +6$ not $f(x) - f(1) = 2x +6 $

Put $x =1$

$\implies 2f(1) = 2+6 \implies f(1)= 4$

Now substitute $f(1)$ in initial equation and solve for $f(8)$

$f(8)  = 2x+ 6 - f(1) = 2\times 8 + 6 - 4 = 18$

Answer (score 0):

If you set $x = 1$ in $f(x) = 2x+6-f(1)$, then you have that
$$f(1) = 2\cdot 1+6 - f(1) $$
which implies that
$$2f(1) = 8 $$
and so $f(1) = 4.$

Therefore, we find that
$$f(x) = 2x+6-f(1) = 2x+6-4=2x+2. $$

We conclude that
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{f(8) = 2\cdot 8+2 = 18. 
} $$

Answer (score 0):

First thing you did wrong was that when you shifted $f(1)$ from RHS to LHS you didn't change the sign. The correct step would have been

> $f(x)+f(1)=2x+6$

But you don't need to do this. Since the term $f(1)$ doesn't vary with $x$, you can just consider it to be some constant c i.e., $f(1)=c$.

Now it's just simple linear equation. First substitute $x=1$ to get $f(1)$ then use it to get original function $f(x)$. Now just substitute $x=8$ to get final answer.